# Render A text from python Flask input

Tags: python, flask

**i need to render a text from a text input field,**
**this is my app.py**

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/",methods=['POST'])
def data():
    text = request.form['command']
    return render_template("exploit.html") + text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=1)
```

and this my exploit.html code

```
<body>
<form action="POST">
    <label>Command: </label>
    <input type="text" name = "command"> 
    <input type = "submit" value = "send">
</form>
```

actually i'm trying some remote code execution from that text input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass variables to jinja2 templates by adding arguments to render_template function.

```
    return render_template("exploit.html", text = text)
```

They can be accessed later by using {{}}, like so:

```
<body>
{{text}}
<form action="POST">
    <label>Command: </label>
    <input type="text" name = "command"> 
    <input type = "submit" value = "send">
</form>
```